# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo'

Tags: sitecore-client, glass-mapper, json

I am getting this error when the datsource model have sitecore image field. the below code written in the .cshtml file and the model is binding via Glass mapper.

```
<script>
 var var1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

any help to resolve this issue

Comment: Do not serialize the whole Model. Serialize only what you need from that model

Comment: model is common and have so many fields. if any of the field is sitecore Image type, problem is coming

Answer (score 1):

Solution above Sumit provided will also works for you, you can try below things as well.

1. Apply `[JsonIgnore]` to navigational properties
2. In `global.asax` `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`
3. Serialize the data

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gridDataResult.GridData, Formatting.None);
return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Hope this as well and do not serialize whole modal only serialize whatever needed from modal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to use Sitecore "Image" data type. I don't have control to modify any properties to add [JsonIgmore].

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are circular references in your object hierarchy which is not supported by the JSON serializer. You could pick up only the properties you need in the view:

I would suggest you to create a class like this for Image and bind the image properties.

```
public class DataItemImage
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }

    public DemoDataItemImage(Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField obj)
    {
        string mediaUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(obj.MediaItem);
        ID = obj.MediaItem.ID.ToString();
        Source = mediaUrl;
        Width = obj.Width;
        Height = obj.Height;
        Alt = obj.Alt;
    }
}
```

And then use this to create the Json object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this may work but currenlty I am using glass mapper and Image field to map sitecore fields. is there any way to use same without circular issue

Comment: @shahul Did you try this? `var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});`